# mysql truncates integer to an strange number on find and insert

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent

I'm using Eloquent of Laravel in php to insert and find a record.
What happens is that when I insert an integer, here it's -1001094515039, it changes that to -367135071 and stores it in the field.
Field type is Bigint with 20 characters length, I have tried storing it in a text type field and a Varchar one, but the same thing happens.
Also when I manually change that to -1001094515039 in phpMyAdmin, and I try to find it using Eloquent's find method, it doesn't give me that record!

The script was working in my first server with PHP 5.X, current server uses php 7.x, which I think might be the case!
I have tried the option thing where we set MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE to 16 * 1024 * 1024 but that didn't work either.

Here are PHP max, min values for int:

min int: -9223372036854775808
max int: 9223372036854775807

Any solutions?

---

UPDATE:

This is how I Insert Data:

```
$Group = new Group();
$Group->id = -1001094515039;
$Group->registerdate = "2017-02-03 00:56:01";
$Group->name = "Test Ginger 2";
$Group->owner_id = 81997375;
$Group->save();
```

var_dump($Group->save()) Result is:
http://textuploader.com/d1oo7

Highlights:

```
[attributes:protected] => Array
            (
                [id] => -1001094515039
                [registerdate] => 2017-02-03 00:56:01
                [name] => Test Ginger 2
                [owner_id] => 81997375
            )
```

Show Create Table Result:

```
CREATE TABLE `groups` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
 `owner_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `acive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `autorounds` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `timezone` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Pacific/Easter',
 `registerdate` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `owner_id` (`owner_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Result of the Insert:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/jb6lNmx.png]

Comment: Just one quick comment.  Setting a "character length" for an integer is purely cosmetic.  It's basically a hint for the mysql command line utility, and has nothing to do with the storage allowance.  With that said, this is clearly a php integer issue.  See this:  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: Start with finding out your PHP_INT_SIZE, and update the question with that info. You can also provide PHP_INT_MIN and PHP_INT_MAX

Comment: @gview I checked, values seem ok. I didn't set any length for the field actually, mysql itself has its defaults I guess.min int: -9223372036854775808
max int: 9223372036854775807

Comment: Do you need to keep it as integer? can't you simply use varchar?

Comment: @Mojtaba As I said, I tried writing the variable to a varchar field, also a text field. The variable is a telegram's supergroup id that is 15 characters long.

Comment: @RyanVincent Check the new answer, and I'm not using laravel itself, just the standalone package of Eloquent. Laravel Rocks, I'm a Fan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now suspect I understand the problem.

I ran the following var_dumps on a php 5.5 instance and php 7.0 instance. 
    dd(array('RawValue' => -1001094515039), array('using intval()' => intval(-1001094515039)), array('PHP Version' => phpversion()));

Here are the results in:

### 5.5

> array:1 [▼
>     "RawValue" => -1001094515039.0
>   ]
>   array:1 [▼
>     "using intval()" => -367135071
>   ]
>   array:1 [▼
>     "PHP Version" => "5.5.12"
>   ]

### 7.0

> array:1 [▼
>    "RawValue" => -1001094515039
>   ]
>   array:1 [▼
>     "using intval()" => -1001094515039
>   ]
>   array:1 [▼
>     "PHP Version" => "7.0.4"
>   ]

There is some more information in this [link]:http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php , but I suspect the changes to raw numbers and integers in php from 5 to 7 is causing your issue.  wrapping the variable in an intval() should resolve your issue.

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: Thanks for the details, this solves it too and it seems to be the main solution. Casting the integer to string also helped.

Answer (score 2):

What data type are you using to create that field?

I've had the issue when trying to insert a large integer into an int field. The fix has been to alter the field to bigint.

If you are using Laravel for your migrations the data type is:

```
$table->bigInteger('votes');
```

Or in MySQL:

```
        ALTER TABLE table_name 
        MODIFY COLUMN  column_name bigint;
```

More info on the different integer types. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html

Comment: Like I told, field type is bigint, and I tried to insert the same data in a text field too, but no success.

Comment: What value do you see for the variable in question  when you var_dump it to the screen?

Comment: It's the real value I'm trying to insert to the database, but after insert is done and I check the database, it's changed.

Comment: This is not a normal case, and I don't ask a question before searching the whole day to make sure it hasn't happened to others before.

Comment: This then sounds like the same issue I had with data types for that field.  A good way to confirm this is to  var_dump the insert statement eloquent created to perform the insert using         dd($yourEloquentmodel->toSql()) the. Run that on your sql terminal

Comment: It's not an issue with data types, because I can manually insert that value inside phpmyadmin and it works. It's like there's something between php and mysql that changes stuff. Same script works on another server of mine running php 5! It's the same database backup I've restored, I also created another database, same thing

Comment: Interesting. Could you send the output of the ->toSql() dump?

Comment: I'll update the question in a few hours with more info including toSql

Comment: For the table in question it would be great just for validation if you updated the question with the output of:  SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it's a json related problem in php 7 version I'm using.
Data I'm inserting to MySql are extracted from the json response I get from Telegram.

And looks like it can't convert negative numbers, because unsigned integers are ok.
Now I add (string) keyword before any possible negative integers, and the issue is solved.

```
$Group->id = (string) $this->FromChat()->ID;
```

Comment: Will test it and check if it is the issue.. I am too facing this issue in telegram bot api